# How to add localhost URL in google DialogFlow Webhook?

Tags: c#, dialogflow-es

I want to link my c# api to Google DialogFlow but when I enabled webhook and past localhost URL into it, it shows error that local urls can not be added.

Is there any way to add localhost url into webhook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to debug your code locally.You can use https://ngrok.com/ , to host local URLas web URL, This Web URL can be used in webhook .

https://www.sitepoint.com/use-ngrok-test-local-site/

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot do it.** Dialogflow needs public https url.

However you can try some 3rd party tools like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), [webhookrelay](https://webhookrelay.com/)